# Hybrid ODE simulation with very small parameters

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a Hybrid dynamical system using `NDSolve` and `WhenEvent`. I am able to simulate when the parameters are close to `1`. However, the practical value of these parameters are close to `0.001`. When I put in the actual values, one of two things happens (1) Mathematica crashes, (2) inaccurate simulation.

Parameters:

```
R = 0.05;G = .04;L = .001;C1 = .001;E1 = 300;Il = 1;us = 0.5;

xd = Inverse[{{R, 1 - us}, {1 - us, -G}}].{E1, 0};
tmax = 2;
```

Using NDSolve:

```
    sol = NDSolve[{
   x1'[t] == -(R*x1[t] + (1 - u[t])*x2[t] - E1)/L,
   x2'[t] == ((1 - u[t])*x1[t] - G*x2[t])/C1,
   WhenEvent[x1[t]*xd[[2]] - x2[t]*xd[[1]] > 0.001, u[t] -> 0],
   WhenEvent[x1[t]*xd[[2]] - x2[t]*xd[[1]] < -0.001, u[t] -> 1],
   x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 10, u[0] == 0},
  {x1, x2, u}, {t, 0, tmax}, DiscreteVariables -> {u}]
```

Plotting:

```
Plot[{xd[[2]], x2[t] /. sol, x1[t] /. sol, xd[[2]] - 5,xd[[2]] + 5}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 10000, PlotRange -> Full]
Plot[u[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 2000]
Plot[{(x1[t]*xd[[2]] - x2[t]*xd[[1]]) /. sol}, {t, 0, tmax},PlotPoints -> 10000, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Simulation works well when `L=C1=1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me with `L = C1 = .001`, it's just slow (326 seconds).  Looking at the output shows why:

```
Plot[u[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 2000]
Plot[u[t] /. sol, {t, tmax - 0.01, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are lots of events to detect!

```
$Version
(* 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019) *)
```

Comment: Hi, You are correct, it works well. However, I posted the wrong system yesterday. It works well because it is a linear system. I made the correction to the current system. Same issues, if L=C1=1, every simulates fine. But when put L=C1=0.001. It does not work.